# How to resize the path inside the SVG tag like images

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a below facebook icon SVG code

```html
  <svg version="1.1" height="40px" width="40px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 291.319 291.319" style="enable-background:new 0 0 291.319 291.319;" xml:space="preserve">
                <g>
                    <path style="fill:#3B5998;" d="M145.659,0c80.45,0,145.66,65.219,145.66,145.66c0,80.45-65.21,145.659-145.66,145.659
              S0,226.109,0,145.66C0,65.219,65.21,0,145.659,0z" />
                    <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M163.394,100.277h18.772v-27.73h-22.067v0.1c-26.738,0.947-32.218,15.977-32.701,31.763h-0.055
              v13.847h-18.207v27.156h18.207v72.793h27.439v-72.793h22.477l4.342-27.156h-26.81v-8.366
              C154.791,104.556,158.341,100.277,163.394,100.277z" />
                </g>
            </svg>
```

The F logo inside the circle, I want to make it smaller, I'm trying to figure out how to do it, but no success, I have multiple SVG icons like this which I need to make smaller.

Could anyone help me with the logic?

Comment: I'd suggest downloading Inkscape of other vector graphics editor and editing with that. It will take some learning, but it is way faster than resizing that path manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [transform-box :](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box) fill-box;

> The transform-box CSS property defines the layout box to which the
>   transform and transform-origin properties relate.

In the example below, the symbol `f` size is reduced by 20%

```css
.facebook {
transform-box: fill-box;
transform-origin: center center;
transform: scale(0.8); 
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" height="40px" width="40px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 291.319 291.319" style="enable-background:new 0 0 291.319 291.319;" xml:space="preserve">
            <g>
                <path style="fill:#3B5998;" d="M145.659,0c80.45,0,145.66,65.219,145.66,145.66c0,80.45-65.21,145.659-145.66,145.659
          S0,226.109,0,145.66C0,65.219,65.21,0,145.659,0z" />
             </g> 
  <g>   
    <path class="facebook" style="fill:#fff;" d="M163.394,100.277h18.772v-27.73h-22.067v0.1c-26.738,0.947-32.218,15.977-32.701,31.763h-0.055
          v13.847h-18.207v27.156h18.207v72.793h27.439v-72.793h22.477l4.342-27.156h-26.81v-8.366
          C154.791,104.556,158.341,100.277,163.394,100.277z" />
            </g>
        </svg>
```

BONUS

### JS animation of resizing the `f` character on hover.

See comments for explanation.

```js
var svg1 = document.getElementById("svg1"),
  scale = document.getElementById('an_scale'),
  reduce = document.getElementById('an_reduce');
  
 svg1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
   scale.beginElement();
}); 

   svg1.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
   reduce.beginElement();
});
```

```css
.facebook {
transform-box: fill-box;
transform-origin: center center;
fill:#fff;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" height="40px" width="40px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 291.319 291.319" style="enable-background:new 0 0 291.319 291.319;" xml:space="preserve">
           
                <path style="fill:#3B5998;" d="M145.659,0c80.45,0,145.66,65.219,145.66,145.66c0,80.45-65.21,145.659-145.66,145.659
          S0,226.109,0,145.66C0,65.219,65.21,0,145.659,0z" />
      
    <path class="facebook"  transform="scale(0.8)" d="M163.394,100.277h18.772v-27.73h-22.067v0.1c-26.738,0.947-32.218,15.977-32.701,31.763h-0.055
          v13.847h-18.207v27.156h18.207v72.793h27.439v-72.793h22.477l4.342-27.156h-26.81v-8.366
          C154.791,104.556,158.341,100.277,163.394,100.277z" >
      <!-- `F` symbol enlargement animation  -->
    <animateTransform id="an_scale"
       attributeName="transform"
    type="scale"
    begin="indefinite"
    dur="0.4s"
    values="0.8;1.5"
    fill="freeze"/> 
             <!-- `F` symbol reduce animation  -->    
        <animateTransform id="an_reduce"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="scale"
      begin="indefinite"
      dur="0.4s"
      values="1.5;0.8"
      fill="freeze"/> 
    </path>  
            
        </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using css class ?

```
.small50
{
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: scale(.5);
}

.small70
{
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform: scale(.7);
}

then

<svg class="small50">...</svg>

or

<g class="small50">...</g>

or

<path class="small70"></path>
```

Comment: It's making the whole SVG small in size, I want to make the Icon present inside to make it small.

Comment: ... Then put it where you want it... on the <g> or the <path> tag...

Comment: It works, I applied it on the path, but now the content is going to extreme corners, how to make it in the center?

Comment: Modify the center point with transform-origin: center center; in the class